# Grails urlmapping using id and name

Tags: grails, url-mapping

hey all, i have a question about urlmapping in grails. I'm trying to make seo friendly url's using a page name and id. I got the follwing in my URLMapping:

```
class UrlMappings {

static mappings = {
    "/$id/$name"{
        controller = "page"
        action = "view"
    }
    "500"(view:'/error')
    "/"(controller:"index")
  }
}
```

Witch is working, but.... the id won't clear in the urlbar, so the first time i click a link all goes well: http://localhost:8080/SuurdGasControl/2/Gasmetingen

But for the next page it shows: http://localhost:8080/SuurdGasControl/2/6/Ontgassen

note that the id "2" hasn't been removed...

Any help or thoughts?

**UPDATE**

URLMapping now looks like this:

```
class UrlMappings {

  static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
                // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    name stfu: "/id/$id/$name" {
        controller = 'page'
        action = 'view'
    }

    "500"(view:'/error')
    "/"(controller:"index")

  }
}
```

Creating a link is as simple as:

```
<g:link mapping="stfu" params="[id: pageId, name: pageName]">${oNavigationInstance.toString()}</g:link>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a named URL mapping as described on http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#namedMappings