# Grails login and URL Mapping

Tags: grails

I have a homepage with a login but when I run the project, I have this problem:

> Unable to create URL for mapping `[/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]` and parameters `[{action=authenticate}]`. Parameter `[controller]` is required, but was not specified!

I have no idea what's missing in my url mapping. My url mapping contains this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }


        "/homepage" (view: "/layouts/homepage")
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

I tried to declare `"/homepage/$action?"(controller: "SponsorController", action: "authenticate")` but the problem continues.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5179446/480536

Comment: What is the actual url you are trying to hit?

Comment: Problem solved... In GSP, I have a <g:form> with an action and missing declare the controller.